# How to get the value from an input in my codebehind while using @keyup

Tags: c#, vue.js

I have an input box that the user types a phone number and it formats it for them.

```
<label>Primary Phone Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" placeholder="Primary Phone Number" v-model="primaryPhone" maxlength="12" @keyup="formatPhone" />
```

I have my formatting for the phone number below using Vue.js.

```
formatPhone: function (event) {
    if (['Arrow', 'Backspace', 'Shift'].includes(event.key)) {
        this.preventNextIteration = true;
        return;
    }
    if (this.preventNextIteration) {
        this.preventNextIteration = false;
        return;
    }

    if (this.step === 4 && event.target.id === 'primaryPhone') {
        var a = this.primaryPhone.replace(/-/g, '').match(/(\d{1,10})/g)[0];

        this.primaryPhone = a.replace(/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,4})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
    }
}
```

My submit button then runs my btnSubmit function on the code behind like so

```
<button  id="submit" v-show="agreement === true" class="btn" runat="server"  onserverclick="btnSubmit" style="float:right">Submit</button>
```

I need to get the value of the input box in my C# code behind. I know that I cannot use `runat="server"` because this will throw the server tag is not well formed with the `@keyup`. So I tried to get my value in C# using `Request["primaryPhone"]` or `Request.Form["primaryPhone"]` and neither worked. Both said that the object was undefined. How can I get my value in the code behind while using my validation?

I thought about using a hidden field running at the server and just setting that value to the value of my input as a last resort. I feel like there might be a simpler way though.

Comment: You'll need to POST that data to your webserver for it to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting a name for your input. Try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Primary Phone Number" v-model="primaryPhone" maxlength="12" @keyup="formatPhone" />
```

Why does the `name` param matters ?

When the browser makes an HTTP request because of a form submit

- it looks at all `input` descendants that are **not disabled**.
- after that, depending on the type of input (text, radio, checkbox) it gets their value.
- when making the request it needs to fill in a list of `key`, `value` pairs (this actually depends on the enc type). The key for each input is the value of the `name` attribute and **not the id**.

Comment: It was really that simple.. Could you please explain why that would matter/make a difference?